# Is it okay when a base class has only one derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am creating a password module using OOD and design patterns. The module will keep log of recordable events and read/write to a file. I created the interface in the base class and implementation in derived class. Now I am wondering if this is sort of bad smell if a base class has only one derived class. Is this kind of class hierarchy unnecessary? Now to eliminate the class hierarchy I can of course just do everything in one class and not derive at all, here is my code.

```
class CLogFile
{
public:
    CLogFile(void);
    virtual ~CLogFile(void);

    virtual void Read(CString strLog) = 0;
    virtual void Write(CString strNewMsg) = 0;
};
```

The derived class is:

```
class CLogFileImpl :
    public CLogFile
{
public:
    CLogFileImpl(CString strLogFileName, CString & strLog);
    virtual ~CLogFileImpl(void);

    virtual void Read(CString strLog);
    virtual void Write(CString strNewMsg);

protected:
    CString & m_strLog; // the log file data
    CString m_strLogFileName; // file name
};
```

Now in the code

```
CLogFile * m_LogFile = new CLogFileImpl( m_strLogPath, m_strLog );

m_LogFile->Write("Log file created");
```

My question is that on one hand I am following OOD principal and creating interface first and implementation in a derived class. On the other hand is it an overkill and does it complicate things? My code is simple enough not to use any design patterns but it does get clues from it in terms of general data encapsulation through a derived class.

Ultimately is the above class hierarchy good or should it be done in one class instead?

Comment: If you can see yourself or others extending the class later in the future, then no, it's not overkill. You should know, though, that the vtable generated for your classes does consume memory for each descendant of a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in fact I believe your design is good. You may later need to add a mock or test implementation for your class and your design makes this easier.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on how likely it is that you'll have more than one behavior for that interface.

Read and write operations for a file system might make perfect sense now.  What if you decide to write to something remote, like a database?  In that case, a new implementation still works perfectly without affecting clients.

I'd say this is a fine example of how to do an interface.

Shouldn't you make the destructor pure virtual?  If I recall correctly, that's the recommended idiom for creating a C++ interface according to Scott Myers.

Comment: This explains a little bit better why inheritance is the right choice in this instance.

Comment: destructor virtual, not pure virtual

Comment: Yes, pure virtual.  See Scott Meyers "Effective C++": http://books.google.com/books?id=Qx5oyB49poYC&pg=PT91&lpg=PT91&dq=scott+meyers+effective+C%2B%2B+pure+virtual+destructor&source=bl&ots=KKr2sMp1jU&sig=nnH-dmzK5UQj9Z1OBrdx5kCbfN4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VED0UIKvOfDx0wGd6YCQCw&ved=0CG4Q6AEwCA

Comment: I have to admit that I see only one interface in this case for foreseeable future but the idea of separating the interface and implementation is what attracted me in the first place. This can pave way for other things in the future. In a separate module where I had much more methods in the interface I was pleasantly surprised that I could readily use template design pattern just because I had this kind of class hierarchy there as well. So i see this as good principal in general perhaps irrespective of different behavior.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I feel like any 'worker class' should have an 'interface' even if it demands just one derived class for now and we don't immediately see the need for different behavior.

Comment: I don't agree that everything should have an interface.  Model objects?  No.  But things with behavior?  Yes, it's not overly complex and could be worth the effort.

Comment: @duffymo I think we mean the same thing, things with behavior is what I described as 'worker classes' (loosely speaking). I think a lot of classes will fall under this category but not data classes or model objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is acceptable, even with only 1 implementation of your interface, but it may be slower at run time (slightly) than a single class.  (`virtual` dispatch has roughly the cost of following 1-2 function pointers)

This can be used as a way of preventing dependencies on clients on the implementation details.  As an example, clients of your interface do not need to be recompiled just because your implementation gets a new data field under your above pattern.

You can also look at the `pImpl` pattern, which is a way to hide implementation details without using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

No. If there's no polymorphism in action there's no reason for inheritance and you should use the refactoring rule to put the two classes into one. **"Prefer composition over inheritance".**

Edit: as @crush commented, "prefer composition over inheritance" may not be the adequate quotation here. So let's say: if you think you need to use inheritance, think twice. And if ever you are really sure you need to use it, think about it once again.

Comment: Doesn't composition refer to adding objects of the otherwise inherited classes as members?

Comment: What happens when a future developer comes along and needs to create a new CLogFile implementation? Does the task of splitting it into two classes instead of one fall to them?

Comment: If there had been any content in the base class yes... But in this case there is no content at all, the base class can even be totally deleted.

Comment: @crush : This can be the case for **any class** with a behaviour in a program. If the class is kept 'little', following the `Single Responsibility Principle`, then it is not difficult to extract the Interface of the already existing class, and then implement a second class that would respect the extracted Interface.

Comment: The base class is the equivalent of an interface in Java. It defines how the class is to be interfaced with.

Comment: so you define a interface for each and any class of yours ? I don't believe you.

Comment: I, in fact, do believe crush. Thats a purpose of classes, isn't it? Heck, I can even define an interface for my procedural C library. Although it's not grouped as nicely as I can group it with classes.

Comment: @StephaneRolland No, you don't define an interface for each and every class. You define them for ones where it is relevant. This instance is the proper time for inheritance, whereas `class Object {}` might use CLogFile as a composite in itself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance Might want to understand the principal before preaching it.

Comment: @StephaneRolland It should probably be called CLog. Thats a bit more sensible, as you can e.g. abstract it to use a socket instead of a file.

Comment: @JonasWielicki This is what ran through my mind as well and it strike me that it would be always good to create interface (base class) for any class in a good object oriented design.

Comment: Okay, so you got it all! :-) `No you don't define an interface for each and every class. You do it when it's relevent`. There's nothing to add: You think CLogFile might be relevent, and I don't. Until I'm shown something in the code that makes me think it is relevent, I think the CLogFile interface is **useless**.

Comment: @StephaneRolland It's relevant as defined by the desired application of the class. CLogFile (or CLog more appropriately named) would be a component of another class that implements your cited "Composition over inheritance" rule. How about you provide some code showing that it is not relevant as an interface? The burden of proof is on you.

Comment: @crush you are right, it is a decision I make, that I must make for many object I design. But the proof is currently here: There is only one inheriting class. **It's is the proof there is no polymorphism in action.** so no need for a base class for the moment. Not for the moment. As soon as the need is there, I'll go for the interface as its inherited subclasses.

Comment: there is a good book about the danger of too much OOP wherever, above all where it is not needed: "Refactoring by Martin Fowler". One of the greatest book I have read.

Comment: But there is obvious intention for various methods of logging in the design of this class. It is absolutely obvious that the author intends to lay groundwork for others (himself included) to expand upon how CLog reads and writes. In fact, according to the `Single Responsibility Principle` he would need to make 3 classes: `CLog`, `CLogReader`, and `CLogWriter`. The latter two being components of the first.

Comment: No one can be more blind than **the one who doesn't want to see**.

Comment: I provided an example of your suggestion for the author to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Your model works well with the factory model where you work with a lot of shared-pointers and you call some factory method to "get you" a shared pointer to an abstract interface.

The downside of using pImpl is managing the pointer itself. With C++11 however the pImpl will work well with being movable so will be more workable. At present though, if you want to return an instance of your class from a "factory" function it has copy semantic issues with its internal pointer.

This leads to implementers either returning a shared pointer to the outer class, which is made non-copyable. That means you have a shared pointer to one class holding a pointer to an inner class so function calls go through that extra level of indirection and you get two "new"s per construction. If you have only a small number of these objects that isn't a major concern, but it can be a bit clumsy.

C++11 has the advantage of both having unique_ptr which supports forward declaration of its underlying and move semantics. Thus pImpl will become more feasible where you really do know you are going to have just one implementation.

Incidentally I would get rid of those `CString`s and replace them with `std::string`, and not put C as a prefix to every class. I would also make the data members of the implementation private, not protected.

Comment: Why should he replace with std::string? That is just as much of a dependency is it not? Other than it being a superior string encapsulator I mean.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative model you could have, as defined by [Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), both referenced by Stephane Rolland, implemented the following model.

First, you need three different classes:

```
class CLog {
    CLogReader* m_Reader;
    CLogWriter* m_Writer;

    public:
        void Read(CString& strLog) {
            m_Reader->Read(strLog);
        }

        void Write(const CString& strNewMsg) {
            m_Writer->Write(strNewMsg);
        }

        void setReader(CLogReader* reader) {
            m_Reader = reader;
        }

        void setWriter(CLogWriter* writer) {
            m_Writer = writer;
        }
};
```

CLogReader handles the Single Responsibility of reading logs:

```
class CLogReader {
    public:
        virtual void Read(CString& strLog) {
            //read to the string.
        }
};
```

CLogWriter handles the Single Responsibility of writing logs:

```
class CLogWriter {
    public:
        virtual void Write(const CString& strNewMsg) {
            //Write the string;
        }
};
```

Then, if you wanted your CLog to, say, write to a socket, you would derive CLogWriter:

```
class CLogSocketWriter : public CLogWriter {
    public:
        void Write(const CString& strNewMsg) {
            //Write to socket?
        }
};
```

And then set your CLog instance's Writer to an instance of CLogSocketWriter:

```
CLog* log = new CLog();
log->setWriter(new CLogSocketWriter());
log->Write("Write something to a socket");
```

**Pros**
The pros to this method are that you follow the Single Responsibility Principle in that every class has a single purpose. It gives you the ability to expand a single purpose without having to drag along code which you would not modify anyways. It also allows you to swap out components as you see fit, without having to create an entire new CLog class for that purpose. For instance, you could have a Writer that writes to a socket, but a reader that reads a local file. Etc.

**Cons**
Memory management becomes a huge concern here. You have to keep track of when to delete your pointers. In this case, you'd need to delete them on destruction of CLog, as well as when setting a different Writer or Reader. Doing this, if references are stored elsewhere, could lead to dangling pointers. This would be a great opportunity to learn about Strong and Weak references, which are reference counter containers, which automatically delete their pointer when all references to it are lost.

Comment: To me, this looks more complicated because it is overly divided. read/write can also be one module for file or anything else. Future expansion looks more complicated as well.

Comment: Future expansion is actually less complicated. Also, what if you want to read from a socket, but write to a file (as I mentioned). Using components allows you to mix and match as you wish, without having to create classes to handle every variation. It also enables the use of factories. In fact, most frameworks .NET, Java, Qt for C++, etc. use this style.